# How to pass a value returned by function inside another function

Tags: javascript

I have a function which is looking for a specific element in an interval:

```
function waitForElementToDisplay(selector, callback, checkFrequencyInMs, timeoutInMs) {
  var startTimeInMs = Date.now();
  (function loopSearch() {
    if (document.querySelector(selector) != null) {
      callback();
      return;
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (timeoutInMs && Date.now() - startTimeInMs > timeoutInMs)
          return;
        loopSearch();
      }, checkFrequencyInMs);
    }
  })();
}
```

I use this function in another function which should return gameCode attribute from an element:

```
function getGameCode() {
  return waitForElementToDisplay(".gamesinfo-popup__button",
    function() {
      return document.querySelector(".gamesinfo-popup__button").getAttribute('data-game-code')
    }, 1000, 9000);
}
```

However when I call `getGameCode()` function I get undefined. Calling each parts one by one works as expected so I am guessing that the problem is that I am not passing the returned value inside `getGameCode()` function properly. What is the correct way of doing this?